# Clicked EFI volume kali installation, mac stuck

Tags: mac, macos, efi

So, i was following this link -> http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-dual-boot-on-mac-hardware

And i selected EFI volume instead of kali or macos. It went to a black screen!

I force restarted it, holding the power button for a while, it got turned off. (I knew that because the trackpad stopped responding to touch)

I started it again, nothing happens. No light on the screen, no color, just black.

Tried this 7-8 times, nothing!!

Refind was installed on my Macbook pro, 15 inch, 2016 model

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you’ll want to do resolve nearly every power related issue on a Mac is to reset the SMC, or System Management Controller. This will dump and reset settings for anything power management related, and is long known to resolve problems with things like fans, heat, sleeping problems, and of course, display issues.

On any modern MacBook Pro or MacBook Air with a built-in battery, which is just a bout all of them nowadays, this is how you do that:

Shut down the Mac and connect it to your MagSafe adapter and a wall outlet as usual

Hold down the Shift+Control+Option+Power button at the same time for a few seconds

Release all keys at the same time, then boot the Mac as usual

Answer (score 0):

If your Mac supports internet recovery, you can network boot directly to Apple's servers over the internet. Use Disk Utility to reformat your drive and then get macOS reinstalled from the network.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Be sure to be patient with Option - Command - R and make sure you get connected to WiFi or Ethernet to internet in the recovery screens before giving up on Internet Recovery. You might need to try several times or connect to another network if yours is filtered.

If that doesn't work, boot your Mac in target disk mode and connect it to an OS that can repartition / reformat / reinstall the OS of your choice.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462

If that doesn't work, have someone you trust make you a bootable USB drive to reinstall macOS. It fits on consumer USB media - 8 GB should be enough.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Comment: I need the bootloader page for internet or any recovery. It does not light up. Just black screen!!

Comment: @KakshilShah You shouldn't - internet recovery works from firmware even without an internal drive connected last time I checked. What exact model Mac do you have?

Comment: Macbook pro, 15 inch, 2016 model.

Comment: How do i do anything, i dont see anything at all! Holding any keys alt, cmd r, does not show anything!

Comment: ***If that doesn't work, boot your Mac in target disk mode...***

Comment: Ohh, will try that out!

Comment: That didn't work! Somehow this solved it -> http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/22/fix-macbook-pro-booting-black-screen/